# Can a headache be caused solely by a smell?

Tags: headache, migraine, triggers, smell

I've bought some air fresheners a while back, and since then I get migraine attacks more often. I didn't fully realize that it might be the cause for my headaches, until I didn't use it for a week and I was fine.

Yesterday I just used it again and it was followed by a headache. I thought it might be because of the chemicals, or maybe I am allergic to it, So I tried a new one today, same result.

My question is, is there any scientific reason that could claim a headache caused by just a smell?!

Comment: Interesting question.  Clinically, yes it happens.  But I actually don't know how that works neurologically and am curious to see if there is an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I was thinking about asking this on Biology, but the boyz on biology are sensitive, they don't like questions like this.

Comment: There is a fine line for sure in terms of scope, often blurry.  But BioSE is a good goal for a well-functioning site, I'd love to see us get there!

Answer (score 4):

Certainly, headaches can be caused by a variety of smells, perfumes, paints, gasoline, bleach and yes, air fresheners.

A study in 200 [migraine patients](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23832131) showed perfumes were the first most common cause when headaches are attributed to odors (75%), followed by paints (42%), gasoline (28%) and bleach (27%)

Comment: That's exactly the case for me. I can never use a perfume because a headache is guaranteed. Thanks for the link and clarification!